# Problems with my sitemap.txt in Google Search Console for indexing PDFs

Tags: google-search, pdf

Here is the contents of my sitemap.txt

```
http://www.merrittnet.org/Papers/
http://www.merrittnet.org/Marmot/
```

in these 2 directories are around 50 PDF files it has been around 5 days now and when I search using

```
https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=acf88dbf364fe0f82
```

(search words like "water" or "hydrology" should return some hits but dont or FileType:pdf)

Is there some special configuration that needs to be done for a folder of PDFs

also to note in these directories I have an index.php that dynamically creates href links for all.pdf files in that directory.

Comment: Sitemaps don't guarantee that things will be indexed, see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox

Comment: Also worth noting that even if Google does choose to index these 433 PDF files, it will likely take weeks unless your site has exceptionally strong authority.

Comment: Your sitemap should contain every URL that you want indexed, not just the directories.   You should add all the PDFs to your sitemap.      You should also enable HTTPS for your site.

Comment: Hey Stephen I just entered the directories since I was hoping to allow indexing of newly added PDFs , now I do have a index.php in each directory that creates a href link to each PDF as they are added will that noot work?